# sometimes I get locked out of 'konsole'. Why could this be?

Tags: konsole, fluxbox

I have been using KDE's konsole as a terminal emulator.

However, sometimes the konsole window is selected (the window bar is showing  that) but my input is not being read to bash. The cursor is not blinking.

This happens after I alt-tabbed away did something in some other window, and came back. I don't believe it happened in other circunstances.

In this situation, I have to click the konsole to get input to bash again.

Does anyone know what might be happening?

How can I resume typing to the bash running inside the konsole, without using the mouse?

(if it is relevant, I currently use fluxbox as my window manager. But the problems seems to afflict only konsole, not, for example, firefox)

Comment: Are you sure the konsole window has regained focus?

Comment: the bar on the top of the window has changed color. I will test it by sending away every other window to a different workspace, the next time the problem manifests.